# How to determine how big array is and then display all the information inside?

Tags: c#, arrays

**GOAL**

Hello all, I would like to allow the user to type in how big the array should be for example: "I would like the array to be 5" therefore only 5 objects can fit inside it.

The next step I would like to accomplish is, how to then display everything inside the array.

**APPLICATION**

This is what I have tried so far I feel like I'm close but I just cannot work it out.

```
    int Number;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter some numbers");
        Number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] Marks = new int[Number];
        while (Number != -1)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Enter some more numbers or press -1 to finish");
            Number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Marks.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Marks[i]);
        }
```

**PROBLEM**

If you haven't worked it out yet, the program only takes in the first entered value as the size of the array (that is what I wanted) but instead of then displaying everything inside it only posts how big the array is for example

Number = 5

0
0
0
0
0

Five zeroes appear like such.

**SIDENOTE**

As an additional cry for help, I would like the program to after taking the size of the array to limit the user from entering above the index field.

For example: The array is 5, therefore 6 entries cannot be entered or an error would appear.

Comment: You are not assigning the input to the `Marks` array.  You will need a variable to keep track of where in the array you are, and then you will need to assign the input value to an element in the `Marks` array.

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment - which is not in and of itself a bad thing, but you should be clear if it is or not.

Comment: Instead of doing while (Number != -1) you can do a for loop to loop through 0 to number and assign the marks[i] to the input number which will make it so you only enter in the correct amount of numbers.

Comment: Nah @Tim, it isn't I've been keeping up to date over the summer for going back to university, I've been trying to recall certain things from memory and this one just hasn't stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

After taking in some of the information given to me, I gave it another crack and this is what I achieved.

```
 Console.WriteLine("Enter the size of the array");
        int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] marks = new int[number];
        for (int i = 0; i < marks.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter some more numbers", i + 1);
            marks[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < marks.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nData #{0}: {1}\n", i + 1, marks[i]);
        }
```

**EXPLANATION**

Okay so after telling the user to enter the size of the array, the array was assigned to, lets say 5, therefore in the first 'for' loop the program is checking if 'i' is less than the array size, so it can only be entered 5 times, as that is the size of the array.

it is then incrementing 'i' each time around so when it does get to 5 it ends the loop.

The second 'for' loop is checking all of the information and then I am simply saying "New line - Data# {placeholder}: {placeholder} - new line", increment 'i' each time, show what is in the array.

Comment: why not accepting @BradleyDotNET answer and instead giving the solution yourself?

Comment: While he did - help - in getting the problem solved, I think other people stuck on this matter would find it more helpful with my clear and simple answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your loop simply reassigns the `Number` (also, local variables should be camelCase) variable on each iteration. You need to assign the elements of the array and keep an index:

```
int currentIndex = 0;
int input = 0;

while (currentIndex < values.Length && input != -1)
{
   values[currentIndex] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
   currentIndex++;
}
```

Note that the assignment goes into the array, and that we increment the current index each time so that no data is overwritten. Also, be careful with the `Parse` family of functions, they will throw if junk data is thrown at them.

Comment: TryParse can be used to avoid an exception. Invalid input (i.e., TryParse returns false) could be ignored by not assigning anything to the array and not incrementing currentIndex.